# cucumber data table multiple seperate iteration

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

In the following feature file my requirement is to put one `doc_id` for every three field. To clarify, I want to check `ProductName`, `manufacturerName` and `RevisionDate` for every `doc_id`. I came up with following method but I think this is definitely not the preferred one. Can anyone suggest me a better way.

```
Background:
    Given I am in landigpage page after login

Scenario Outline: valid
    When I enter "<doc_id>"
    And I click the search go button
    Then I should get in vault search page
    And Search result of "<field>" should match with database

Examples:
    | doc_id | field            |
    | 15     | ProductName      |
    | 15     | ManufacturerName |
    | 15     | RevisionDate     |

Examples:
    | doc_id | field            |
    | 16     | ProductName      |
    | 16     | ManufacturerName |
    | 16     | RevisionDate     |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single examples table:

```
Background:
    Given I am in landigpage page after login

Scenario Outline: valid
    When I enter "<doc_id>"
    And I click the search go button
    Then I should get in vault search page
    And Search result of "<field>" should match with database

Examples:
    | doc_id | field            |
    | 15     | ProductName      |
    | 15     | ManufacturerName |
    | 15     | RevisionDate     |
    | 16     | ProductName      |
    | 16     | ManufacturerName |
    | 16     | RevisionDate     |
```

I don't see any other way to pass arguments the way you need to. That's what I don't like about Cucumber. It is not that flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bacckground:
  Given I am in landigpage page after login

Scenario Outline: valid
  When I enter "<doc_id>"
  And I click the search go button
  Then I should get in vault search page
  And the search results should match the database
Examples:
  | doc_id |
  | 15     |
  | 16     |
```

and to make this work:

```
When /^I enter "<\w+>"$/ do | doc_id |
  @doc_id = doc_id
  ...
end

Then "the search results should match the database" do
  db_results = db.find(@doc_id)  # or something similar
  ... # compare db_results to actual results
end
```

This still kind of sucks, because you have doc_id's in your Gherkin, you are relying on a prefilled database and you have a scenario outline; but hey lets save that for other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i guess you guys are confusing [Data Tables](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#tables) and scenario outline.
The solution for above is :

```
Background:
Given I am in landingpage page after login

Scenario Outline: valid
When I enter "<doc_id>"
And I select to navigate to search page 
Then Search result of field should match with database
| ProductName      |
| ManufacturerName |
| RevisionDate     |

Examples:
  | doc_id |
  | 15     |
  | 16     |
```

The table can easily be converted to a list or a map that you can use in your step.